# find graph G with 60 vertices and minimum degree 40 such that K4 is not a sub-graph of G.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I had tried to define $K_{30_{30}}$ full Bipartite how and add it more edges.
however, I don't found an easy way to define such graph.

Comment: Did you mean $K_{30,30}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete tripartite graph $K_{20,20,20}$ does the trick.  There are $60$ vertices, each of degree $40$.  Given any $4$ vertices, by the pigeonhole principle, two of them must belong to the same partition set, so are not adjacent, and the given vertices don't form a $K_4$.

Comment: In case OP wants to read more, this is a [Turan graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem)